# Linear Regression with Lognormal Response PYMC3

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3, inference, model-fitting

This is my first attempt to model a linear regression for a response that is lognormally distributed.
I have a dataframe `df` with two variables: the predictor `X` and the response. 
When I plot the `response` vs. the predictor variable `X`, we obtain this nice plot:
[image]

When I plot the distribution of the logarithm of the response `np.log(response)` I obtain something pretty close to a Normal distribution:

. [image]

To model the relationship between `X` and `response` I build the following model,

```
import pymc3 as pm


with pm.Model() as model: 
    a = pm.Normal('a', 0, 10)
    b = pm.Normal('b', 0, 10)
    sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', lower=0, upper=10)

    mu = pm.Deterministic('mu', a + b * df_train[X])

    y_hat = pm.Lognormal('y_hat', mu = mu, sd = sigma, observed = df['response'] )

    trace = pm.sample(2000, tune = 2000)
```

The next step is to measure to which extend the model is correct, so I compute the average response for the dataset, i.e,

```
mu_hat = np.exp(trace['mu'].mean(0)
```

However, when I plot how well this average fits the test set, I observe such a poor fit:

[image]

**Possible Solutions**: I have tried other likelihoods like Normal and Poisson and and I could not achieve a convergence for the model. I was getting an error saying:

`Bad initial energy: inf. The model might be misspecified`.

Any ideas on why this fit fails so miserably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a lognormal distribution of X with a linear response, and maybe some linear error with the magnitude of X.  Without the data, it's hard to tell, but here's my recreation of your problem:

```
matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.lognormal(5, 1, 10000)
y = x * np.random.normal(5,1,10000)

f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(16,12))
sns.scatterplot(x,y, ax=axes[0])
sns.distplot(np.log(y), ax=axes[1])
```

[Scatterplot of x and y, distribution of log(y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90qA0.png)

Then we can model the x coefficient and dependent y error:

```
with pm.Model() as model: 
    sigma = pm.InverseGamma('sigma', mu=(y/x).std(), sd = (y/x).std()/len(x))
    #intercept = pm.Normal('Intercept', 0, sigma=1)
    x_coeff = pm.Normal('x_coeff', (y/x).mean(), sigma=1)

    l = pm.Normal('l', mu=x_coeff, sigma=sigma, observed=y/x)

    trace = pm.sample(3000, tune=1000, cores=4)
```

And now plotting the lines we get:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))
sns.scatterplot(x, y, ax=axes)
for (_,val) in pm.stats.quantiles(trace['x_coeff']).items():
    plt.plot(x, val*x, color='b')
    for (__, sd) in pm.stats.quantiles(trace['sigma']).items():
        plt.plot(x, (val+2*sd)*x, color='r')
        plt.plot(x, (val-2*sd)*x, color='r')
```

[x coefficients plotted with 2*sd positive and negative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyM3J.png)